# Applescript for duplicating a file and adding to an iTunes playlist not working

Tags: applescript, itunes

I'm having problem trying to take a track from  one itunes playlist and adding it to another that has been newly created, this used to work now it doesnt but I dont know if it doesnt work at all or just in my test case

This is my test:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set mainlibrary to library playlist 1
    set list_of_folders to get every folder playlist
    set new_playlistfolder to item 1 of list_of_folders
    set new_playlist to (make user playlist in new_playlistfolder with properties {name:"TestPlayList"})
    try
        set existtrack to (first file track of mainlibrary whose database ID = 14265)
        duplicate existtrack to new_playlist

    on error err_mess
        log err_mess
    end try
end tell
```

and this is what I get when I run it in Applescript editor

```
tell application "iTunes"
    get library playlist 1
        --> library playlist id 14395 of source id 72
    get every folder playlist
        --> {folder playlist id 27010 of source id 72, folder playlist id 29459 of source id 72}
    make with properties {name:"TestPlayList"} at folder playlist id 27010 of source id 72 new user playlist
        --> user playlist id 29721 of source id 72
    get file track 1 of library playlist id 14395 of source id 72 whose database ID = 14265
        --> file track id 20505 of library playlist id 14395 of source id 72
    copy file track id 20505 of library playlist id 14395 of source id 72 to user playlist id 29721 of source id 72
        --> error number -1708
    (*iTunes got an error: Can’t set user playlist id 29721 of source id 72 to file track id 20505 of library playlist id 14395 of source id 72.*)
end tell
```

Any ideas.

thanks Paul

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big expert but I have a similar script and instead of

```
(...)
duplicate existtrack to new_playlist
(...)
```

I have got:

```
(...)
set t to (get location of existtrack)
add t to new_playlist
(...)
```

Would it help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to write this line:

```
duplicate existtrack to new_playlist
```

as:

```
duplicate existtrack to playlist new_playlist
```